# Blocking Invalid Users

Tags: php, email, ip, email-validation

I'm developing an online penny auction system on PHP and MySQL.  The problem is that the system gives three bids FREE per signup.

Many people register with invalid email accounts like y95dka9k7y024qn5@mailcatch.com or yopmail.com or any of that.

How I can block these accounts automatic?  For now I do it manually, when I see there are more than 3 accounts invalid.

But how could I do it automatic?

Comment: Try security.stackexchange.com
IMO your only option would be email confirmations.

Comment: the system validates all the emails...  but with those services of disposable emails they can validate those emails

Comment: there is a service that handle that for you : http://ver-email.com , the service is making many checkes including uptodate black listed domains like this one.

Answer (score 1):

During the subscription, when you check the email availability,
check also if the email end with one of theses host name:

- mailcatch.com
- yopmail.com
- ...

If it's the case, just explain that theses hostname are forbidden.

Comment: Yes.. but the list is bigger than that.. and how can i know all of this?

Comment: and how can i block emails like alex1@gmail.com, alex2@gmail.com alexn@gmail.com? with the same ip?